# Can you use the same word twice?

Tags: grammar, repetition

In the sentence below the word "easy" and "easier" are used.  Is it okay to make this sentence?

> "Because it is easy to make the characters bigger, it's easier to read it."

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but it doesn't make much sense.  That characters are easier to read when they're bigger is independent of how difficult it is to actually provide bigger characters.

Comment: Large fonts help make reading easier. "Reading is made easier thanks to large fonts/characters"

Comment: Sounds clumsy to me.

Comment: Your final _it_ does not have an antecedent to refer back to. “Because it is easy to make the characters bigger, it’s easier to read [what?]”. And, as others have mentioned, it’s not easier to read ‘it’ (whatever ‘it’ may be) because it’s easy to make the characters bigger. It may be easier to read because the characters _have been made_ bigger, but that’s a different thing.

Comment: Yes, yes you can. Sometimes it sounds right. Sometimes it sounds awful.

Comment: My reading of this sentence is as follows: *"it is easier to read because it is easier to make the characters bigger"* which doesn't make sense at all. It would be easier to read if you actually DID make the characters bigger, but just the option to do so doesn't change how hard it is to read.

Comment: Just glancing at the first few sentences of a couple of the answers, I think deadrat is much closer to the real answer.  This sentence is grammatically correct, but it's saying something that's logically false, and the wording is poor as a ***stylistic*** issue.

Comment: Only if you really really want to

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it masks the actual question by using an illogical sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sentence is not OK. When you use 'because', you should follow up with something relevant e.g.

> "Because it is easy to make the characters bigger, we should do it as
>   it will aid readability".

In your example, the 2nd clause, whilst related (and people will understand what you  mean) does not follow on correctly. If you rewrote it as

> "Because it is easy to make the characters bigger, we should do it as
>   it will be easier to read"

it would sound better. But even here, the repeated use of 'easy', whilst acceptable, does not sound as good as something along the lines of :

> "Because it is simple to make the characters bigger, we should do it
>   as it will be easier to read".

It just sounds better to not repeat words.

Answer (score 14):

Writers are often advised to avoid using the same word twice in one sentence. But that's really an oversimplified statement.

If you use the same word repeatedly, a sentence can sound repetitive and awkward. In such cases, it's a good idea to look for synonyms of the word you're tempted to repeat, or to rephrase the sentence. If I started to write, "I drove my car to the car dealership where the car salesman sold me a new car", while, that just sounds really bad, way too repetitive. I'd probably recast it to something like, "I drove my car to the auto dealership where the salesman sold me a new vehicle."

But there are many cases where there's no need to worry about repeating words. Short, common words, like articles, prepositions, and pronouns, can be repeated much more freely before a sentence starts to get awkward. Few will even notice that you used "the" or "she" three times in a sentence.

Sometimes you want to deliberately use a word repeatedly for emphasis or parallelism. For example, the phrase "Happy wife, happy life" is pointed precisely because it uses the word "happy" twice (plus a rhyme). It would be considerably less catchy if phrased, "Happy wife, pleasant existence."

The wording in your example sentence is a bit odd, as Deadrat points out. If it was hard to make the characters bigger, but someone still went to the effort, would they cease to be easier to read?

In any case, your use of easy/easier sounds like a mild parallelism. If that was your intention, you probably should make it easy/easy or easier/easier. If that was not your intention, you might want to choose a different word. But "easy" is a short and common enough word that it doesn't sound all that awkward.

Comment: Is that why we say "lead a ___ life"? How about "die a ___ death"? I see that very often. Is it because there's no other way to put it or is it a general expression?

Comment: "Die a _____ death": Hard to see how else you could say that. I suppose you could say "experience a _____ death" or "suffer a _____ death". As to "lead a ____ life", "lead" and "life" aren't really related. you can lead many things other than a life. Like you can lead a horse to water as long as you don't try to make him drink.

Comment: "I drove my car to the auto dealership where the salesman sold me a new vehicle" makes it sound like you ate a thesaurus for lunch: the repetition of the concept is just as awkward as the repetition of the word it replaces. And, arguably, it makes the sentence less clear. I don't know if, by not calling it a car, you're trying to say that you bought some other kind of vehicle. "I drove my car to the dealership, where I bought a new one."

Comment: @Jay I suspect RexYuan meant to say “Live a ____ life”.

Comment: @RexYuan There are many exceptions like that in English to show emphasis.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That was, of course, intended to be an extreme example. But sometimes you really do need to repeat the same concept because the same concept is coming up more than once. In your version, for example, you just say "dealership". How does the reader know you mean a car dealership and not, say, an appliance dealership? "Bought a new one." A new one of what? I could certainly drive my car to a boat dealership or many sorts of dealership. Indeed we would not normally assume that just because you drove somewhere in your car that the place you are going has anything to do with cars. ...

Comment: ... Cars are a very common form of transportation. I use my car to go to the grocery store and the bank and the park and lots of places that have nothing to do with cars. Of course the meaning MIGHT be clear from the larger context, like if the preceding sentence was "I decided to buy a new car." But that just moves the repetition from the quoted sentence to the previous context.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh, good point. That didn't occur to me.

Comment: @Jay Bought one of the things that the dealership sells. What kind of dealership? Well, we're in a context where the only thing that's been mentioned is cars. So any reasonable listener is going to assume I bought a car at the car dealership.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, we are taught in high school English writing class that if you want to say one has a ___ life, you should write "one lead a ___ life" instead of "live a ___ life". So I was wondering if it's because to avoid using "live" and "life" in one sentence

Comment: @RexYuan Probably, yes. Misguided as it is.

Comment: @DavidRicherby But in your version of the sentence, the only reference to cars is what I drove to the dealership. Why would a reader assume that just because I drove a car to a store, that that store must sell cars? Suppose I rode a bicycle the car dealership. Then the sentence becomes, "I rode a bicycle to the dealership, where I bought a new one." How would a reader know it was a car dealership? Would you now assume it's a bicycle dealership? If I said I walked there, would you assume it's a shoe store?

Comment: @Jay Because the choice is that either (a) the speaker is referring to something mentioned earlier or (b) the speaker is referring to some completely random thing that you couldn't possibly guess. (a) seems far more likely. People make this kind of connection all the time. For example, if I say to you, "I'm going to London tomorrow: shall I buy you something?" You infer that "something" means "a souvenir", rather than, say, a dozen eggs and a gerbil.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sure. If someone said, "I decided I needed a new car. So I drove to the dealership ...", I would logically assume he meant a car dealership. If someone said, "I decided I needed a new refrigerator. So I drove my car to the dealership ..." I would assume he meant an appliance dealership. If someone just said, "I drove my car to the dealership ..." with no previous reference, I would have no idea what sort of dealership. The assumption that it must be a car dealership because he drove there would be absurd. Exactly like if someone said, "I walked to the store ...", I would not ...

Comment: ... assume that because he walked there that it must be a shoe store. Anyway, we've both said our piece on this, don't want a drawn out argument Feel free to get in the last word.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically speaking, as long as all the words are in the right place you can repeat words as much as you want to. Repeating words is a matter of style. Many repeated words within a sentence or a paragraph will make it feel simpler. This is a good way of teaching children how to read, by using simple, repetitive language.

Varying the words used makes the sentences seem more sophisticated but it is important to still use words that the target audience will easily understand. A good quality thesaurus will list many words from common to extremely rare so it is a bad idea to try to use all of them before repeating a word! Also, some words which generally mean the same thing have subtle nuances which means they might not always be suitable replacements.

If you are learning English and your vocabulary is smaller than a native speaker's, just use what you feel comfortable with and listen to how native speakers speak as well as noticing both repeated words and different words with the same meaning. Over time you will get better at constructing your own stylish sentences but repeating a word or two will not stand out to most people.

If you are writing a novel and want to appear like a sophisticated author, then you would want to vary the words you use, but even someone whose English is good but still learning can do this with the help of a good editor who is a native speaker who understands what makes good English.

Answer (score 1):

**You can repeat the same word as many times as you need to, in as many forms as you want.** See also: [Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo), which is a grammatically correct sentence.

However, as the same example shows, doing so can make your sentence increasingly difficult to read, as the reader must now parse all possible meanings of the word you're using. Particularly if the word is repeated adjacent to itself.  See also `James, while John had had "had", had had "had had"; "had had" had had a better effect on the teacher.`

So, just because you ***can*** does not mean you ***should***.

As discussed elsewhere, there's two major grammatical errors with your example sentence.

1. The two clauses joined by "because" are in no way dependent on or related to each other. The ease of making characters bigger has no effect on the ease of reading. The *act* of making characters bigger is what has an effect on ease of reading.
2. The final "it" is not referring to anything apparent within the sentence. One may be able to infer that you're referring to *something that is being read*, but that's never stated.

Comment: I prefer the even crazier example sentence, "Wouldn't the sentence 'I want to put a hyphen between the words Fish and And and And and Chips in my Fish-And-Chips sign' have been clearer if quotation marks had been placed before Fish, and between Fish and and, and and and And, and And and and, and and and And, and And and and, and and and Chips, as well as after Chips?"

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine. The first "easy" refers to the difficulty of making characters bigger and the second "easy" refers to the difficulty of reading the characters.